# How do I change the color extracted image to the same color with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, color-picker

I extracted green color in image with `cv2.inRange()`.

But, The colors of the extracted images were all different.

like this --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhQ6P.png)

I want to change extracted image's color to same.

Please help me....

This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test_img.jpg')
height, width = img.shape[:2] 
   
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    
lower_green = (35,45,0,0) 
upper_green = (80, 255, 255,0) 
img_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
img_result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = img_mask) 

cv2.imshow('color',img_result)
```

**Output**

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PpS7.png)

Comment: jpeg means lossy compression. always remember that. and understand what it means. and be sure you understand it completely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `zero` the `B` and `R` dimensions of the image, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test_img.jpg')
height, width = img.shape[:2] 
   
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    
lower_green = (35,45,0,0) 
upper_green = (80, 255, 255,0) 
img_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
img_result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = img_mask)[:, :, 1]

img[:, :, 0] = 0
img[:, :, 2] = 0
img[:, :, 1] = img_result

cv2.imshow('color', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

or if you want a simpler way to output the image, you can use the `matplotlib.pyplot`, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img)
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for answer. but, I run this code. I met error.
`img[::0] = 0` 
`ValueError: slice step cannot be zero`
I think image-processing is very hard....

Comment: The problem is that `img[::0]=0` should be `img[:, :, 0]=0` – 
Michael
6 hours ago

Comment: Thank you for answer. This code is not error. but, Image was not to change same color.... Please help me...

Comment: It works when I try it. Make sure that the image you are working with is not a `gray scale` image, and does actually contain the values in the specified ranges (i.e., otherwise the masked image would be just black)

Comment: I missed `[:, :, 1]` in `bitwise_and`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I could help